# Export Bash command-line-argument variables for use in embedded Expect

Tags: bash, variables, command-line-arguments, expect

The `echo` test shows me my command line variables are working, but how do I pass them, export them, to be used in an embedded `expect`?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo name of script is $0
echo host is $1
echo hostusername is $2
echo hostpassword is $3

expect -c 'spawn ssh -l $2 $1 < ./sf-wall_scp_bash.sh
sleep 2

expect {
"(yes/no)? " {send "yes\n"}
    exp_continue
}

expect {
"?assword" {send "$3\r"}
}
sleep 1
'
```

If invoked with the `expect` shebang, it works like

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set host [lindex $argv 0]
set hostusername [lindex $argv 1]
set hostpassword [lindex $argv 2]


spawn ssh -l $hostusername $host
sleep 2

expect {
"(yes/no)? " {send "yes\n"}
    exp_continue
}

expect {
"?assword" {send "$hostpassword\r"}
}
sleep 1
```

...which works as expected. I need to use `bash` though and embed `expect` because the script is needing to call bash specific commands, functions, built in variables...otherwise simply using the second example would be a working option, but it is not.

I've tried declaring and exporting the command line argument variables, and changing $1, $2, $3 in the first example above respectively to the variable names declared and exported, which works in another script I have in which I am actually declaring the variables within the script...the difference being they are not command line arguments.

```
host=$1
export host
hostusername=$2
export hostusername
hostpassword=$3
export hostpassword
```

as well as just exporting them

```
export host
export hostusername
export hostpassword
```

and attempting the first example above. No change, `expect` continues to claim

> can't read "X": no such variable

In another bash script I was able to successfully export variables by BOTH declaring them and then exporting them as in the example above. But I have not been able to have any such luck with passing `bash` command line argument variables to `expect`

Comment: In your initial script, try double quotes.  Single quotes (by design) do not substitute variables.  You'll need to escape (with a backslash) any literal double quotes or dollar signs in your expect script.

Comment: ssh was designed to force people NOT to put passwords in scripts and files.  expect undoes that design.  Consider ssh keys.  They not hard to implement.

Comment: @jimmcnamara ssh login info is not the only stuff I will be using command-line-arguments for, I just included that in my example. Also, the passwords are not being put in script files, they are dynamic and specific to machines where I cannot setup keys and why they are being provided via CLI arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code with nesting quotes is not easy to write and read. I recommend you use the shell's *here-document* syntax. For example (demo'ing 2 ways of passing `bash` vars to `expect`):

```
$ cat foo.sh
arg1=$1
export arg2=$2

expect << END
puts $arg1
puts \$env(arg2)
END
$ bash foo.sh hello world
hello
world
$
```

I prefer `export var` from the shell and reference it with `$env(var)` in expect as you'll not have to worry about if the `var` has some special chars (like `'`, `"` or spaces) in it.