# Extract EXPECT result to local variable/file

Tags: bash, ssh, expect

I've been struggling with getting the output from a remote server to a local variable or a local file.

**My attempt:**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

my_pass=!!psw!!
server=10.10.10.10
/usr/bin/expect << ENDOFEXPECT
    exp_internal 1      ;# expect internal debugging. remove when not needed
    set PROMPT  ":~ ?# ?"
    set timeout 30

    spawn bash -c "ssh root@$server"  
    expect "assword:"
    send "$my_pass\r"
    expect -re "$PROMPT"

    send -- "df -kh /\r" 
    expect -re "df\[^\n]+\n.+\n(.+\r\n.+)\r\n"
    set command_output $expect_out(1,string)
    send_user "$command_output\r"

    interact
ENDOFEXPECT

echo "====================="
echo " >> $command_output"
```

**Output:**

```
spawn bash -c ssh root@10.10.10.10
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {154725}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "assword:"? no
Password: 
expect: does "\rPassword: " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "assword:"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "assword:"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\rPassword:"
send: sending "!!psw!!\r" to { exp4 }
Gate keeper glob pattern for '' is ''. Not usable, disabling the performance booster.

expect: does " " (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression ""? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) ""
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) ""
send: sending "df -kh /\r" to { exp4 }
Gate keeper glob pattern for 'df[^
]+
.+
(.+
.+)
' is ''. Not usable, disabling the performance booster.

expect: does " " (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "df[^\n]+\n.+\n(.+\r\n.+)\r\n"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no


expect: does " \r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "df[^\n]+\n.+\n(.+\r\n.+)\r\n"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no
Last login: Fri Dec  2 23:58:09 2022 from 10.10.10.1

Welcome to server image 2.2


expect: does " \r\nLast login: Fri Dec  2 23:58:09 2022 from 10.10.10.1\r\r\n\r\nWelcome to server image 2.2\r\n\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "df[^\n]+\n.+\n(.+\r\n.+)\r\n"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no
REMY_SERVER:~ # 
expect: does " \r\nLast login: Fri Dec  2 23:58:09 2022 from 10.10.10.1\r\r\n\r\nWelcome to server image 2.2\r\n\r\n\u001b[?1034h\u001b[1m\u001b[31mREMY_SERVER:~ # \u001b(B\u001b[m" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "df[^\n]+\n.+\n(.+\r\n.+)\r\n"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no
expect: timed out
interact: received eof from spawn_id exp0
=====================
 >>
```

**Expected:**

What I ultimately want is to get the output of `df -kh` into a local variable or even better, append it directly to a local file (on the local machine, not the server on which the command is executed) so that it contains something like:

```
$ cat ./result.txt
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        20G   18G  1,7G  92% /
```

Comment: Are you not able to set up ssh keys  ? that would make things much easier .

Comment: you can just `spawn bash -c "ssh root@$server df -kh >> /the/local/file"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your PROMPT regex is not matching. I see the output has some colour codes in it:

```
expect: does " \r\nLast login: ...REMY_SERVER:~ # \u001b(B\u001b[m" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression  ...
```

It's good to anchor prompt regexes, and to enclose them in braces. Try

```
    set PROMPT { # \S*$}
```

Or, assuming the login shell is bash, set a new prompt that's easier to match:

```
    send "$my_pass\r"
    expect "Welcome to server"
    send -- "PS1='>'\r"
    set PROMPT {>$}
    expect -re $PROMPT
```

---

Next, the relevant code for the question.

```
    send -- "df -kh /\r" 
    expect -re "df\[^\n]+\n.+\n(.+\r\n.+)\r\n"
    set command_output $expect_out(1,string)
    send_user "$command_output\r"
```

I'd adjust your regex a touch:

```
    set cmd "df -kh /" 
    send -- "$cmd\r"
    expect -re "$cmd\r\n(.+)\r\n.*$PROMPT"
```

Then you're capturing and "echoing" the result correctly

```
    set command_output $expect_out(1,string)
    send_user "$command_output\n"
    # use a newline here ......^
```

And to append it to a local file:

```
    set fh [open ./results.txt a]
    puts $fh $command_output
    close $fh
```

Comment: Didn't exactly solve my issue but it helped putting me on the right path. One thing to add expect variables should be escaped, else they will be expanded by shell in my example `\$PROMPT`. Sorry also for the delay, but I was busy with life and only got back to a similar issue now :x

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47183188/7552 for ways to improve that problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1: The proper way is to not use expect and use key pair access :**

**Step #1**

Setup a SSH key pair (google it) and then copy the SSH key to the remote server. To do this I'd recommend using ssh-copy-id.

**Step #2**

Now with the ability to SSH to a server in place using a key, your above problem turns into this:

```
$ ssh root@10.10.10.10 "df -kh"
```

You can get fancy and use here documents (heredocs aka. here-docs) to further enhance this technique.

```
$ ssh root@10.10.10.10 <<EOF
> df -kh
> EOF
```

or put the commands in a file and pass them to ssh:

```
$ ssh root@10.10.10.10 < my.cmds
```

**Method 2: Expect**

See the following, expains how to use it properly and a tool to create expect scripts
https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-automate-tasks-in-ssh/

Comment: Thank you for the answer but sadly I need `expect` to navigate through the intermediary menus in the remote machine. Not to mention that machine has only psw authentication enabled since it is in internal network...

Comment: Yeah then Expect is the way to go or create some sort of automation. Let us know if you find any other ways to do this.